# How to declare a function in Xbase

Tags: xml, xbase

Hi this is probably an odd question but i would like to know how i can declare a function in Xbase.

I was told this is how :

```
declare function prefix:name($parameter as DataType)
as returnDataType {
..code..
};
```

I did this :

```
declare function local:test($i as xs:integer?)
as xs:integer
{
return $i
};
```

But it keep saying that i have a syntax problem

> Expecting expression.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question, the problem is that when you declare a function in Xbase you have to call it after the declaration like this:

```
//declare your function
<test>{local:test("Example")}</test>
```

Otherwise, it will consider it as a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be

```
declare function local:test($i as xs:integer?)
as xs:integer
{
   $i
};
```

In XQuery the `return` keyword is used only in a FLWOR expression.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did (let $i:=1 return $i), I forgot to include it, the problem was not really in the declaration but in the fact that I didn't call the function after declaring it, if you don't  Xbase will consider it as a syntax error..

Comment: Well, in future, it helps to post the actual code that gives you the error, otherwise you're wasting everyone's time.